# Creating a form that serves two wildly different customer types

Tags: forms

I'm creating a form that needs to serve for two customer types.

- The first customer type is inexperienced recruiters who need guidance on how to write good job descriptions.
- The second customer type is experienced recruiters who don't need any support.

---

Beyond having a 'show guidance' switch that the user can toggle on/off, are there any examples of how best to approach this problem, without having to create two forms?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you want to create one form that assists both user types. Multiple solutions could create cognitive load for users that aren't sure which path they should take. Ultimately, you should have the following goals for your solution:

1. A form that you can get through quickly for experienced users
2. A form that can provide support to users that aren't familiar with the process

This could be done with a switch as you have suggested. Or you could keep the guidance on per question basis so it's not "all or nothing".

---

I actually also work on a job board. We've faced a similar issue. We solved for this in the following manner:

[image]

We provide a field title alongside guided copy that we believe can help **all** recruiters, new or seasoned, alongside a "tip" section. Upon selecting this section, the user is shown more in-depth advice on how to write (in this instance, a job title).

[image]

We break the guidance up so we don't overwhelm the user with large pieces of copy. This lets the user choose how much they want to consume. Each user will have varying amount of time that they can dedicate to this task. With each "slide" the guidance gets more detailed.

You could reveal the first tip by default the first time the user enters the page. Another idea is to create an animation that draws attention to the feature if you notice that the user it taking their time at a certain section.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the question that it is about a form where the job description is filled in. Right? In that case, I would offer firstly an input field where the text can be entered directly, and secondly a button that starts a kind of wizard. This wizard guides the user step by step through the creation of a job description.

If you don't need the wizard, you write your job description directly in the form, otherwise the wizard fills it in for you. (How the wizard then works is another question, and whether you can click together a job description with multiple-choice questions I don't know).

If you want to do some upselling, then offer a third button next to the text field and the wizard button saying "We write for you, contact us now for an offer"…

Answer (score 0):

The UXiest approach is to create a single form with the ability to be affected by the toggle when the user select if he/she wants guidance or not.
You can do it programmatically, when the user chooses guidance this is shown as a little tip button at the right or left of each input, when chooses the opposite do not show them.
But, as a matter of performance and programming efficiency it would be better to have those little buttons as default option and let the user decide if he/she needs guidance or not.